# How can I validate that a variable contains an image?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation

Question: How can I know that an image variable has successfully loaded an image from an image url?

The relevant javascript code I have been using is below (I am coding a Chrome extension). I want to grab a random image from an array of images, so I can use (inject) the random image on a webpage. But since I am grabbing the images off some websites that have tons of free images, I want to make sure the random image is not blocked by the free images website for whatever reason (and if it is blocked, then I will try another random image from  maybe another site). I need to know that img.src contains an actual image or not. I am new to javascript, reading a book on it I just got yesterday-- do I need the semicolons or should I just ditch using semicolons? (I come from a background coding in C/C++)

```
const myImages = [];  
    
myImages[0] = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/11/09/rainforest-2048447_960_720.jpg';
myImages[1] = 'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/01a/snail-1397758.jpg';
myImages[2] = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/17/20/35/sloth-2759724_960_720.jpg';
    
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = myImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length)];
img.style.width = '100%';
img.style.height = 'auto';
    
document.querySelector('#pageContent').replaceWith(img);
```

Comment: You can check with `onerror` event in img tag.

Comment: If you only use images that allow you to copy them and serve them from your own webserver, there would not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write logic if image not loaded on image load error.

```js
const myImages = [];  
    
myImages[0] = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/11/09/rainforest-2048447_960_720.jpg';
myImages[1] = 'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/01a/snail-1397758.jpg';
myImages[2] = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/17/20/35/sloth-2759724_960_720.jpg';
    
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = myImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length)];
img.style.width = '100%';
img.style.height = 'auto';

document.querySelector('#pageContent').replaceWith(img);

img.onerror = function() {
    // If image not loaded, write your logic here
};
```

```html
<div id="pageContent">imaged</div>
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! That looks like it would be very useful for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use es6 template literals and instead of template literals use img tag with properties :

```js
var img = `<img src=${myImages.Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length)} width='100%' height='auto'`
    
document.querySelector('#pageContent').appendChield(img);
```

Comment: I just read about that a bit in the javascript book I just got yesterday, I will see if I can implement your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

To validate your variable, use [complete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete).

```
    const myImages = [];

    myImages[0] = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/11/09/rainforest-2048447_960_720.jpg';
    myImages[1] = 'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/01a/snail-1397758.jpg';
    myImages[2] = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/17/20/35/sloth-2759724_960_720.jpg';

    const img = document.createElement('img');

    img.src = myImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length)];
    img.style.width = '100%';
    img.style.height = 'auto';

    img.onerror = function() {
        // If image not loaded, write your logic here

    };

    // complete attribute would be false because the image is not yet loaded.

    console.log(img.complete);

    img.addEventListener("load", () => {
        // complete attribute would be true

        console.log(img.complete);

        document.querySelector('#pageContent').replaceWith(img);
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code below

```
 function checkExist() {
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 
 if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  console.log("exist")
  }
};
 xhttp.open("GET",
 "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/11/09/rainforest-2048447_960_720.jpg",true);    
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sabri, I am going to have to study your code a bit but I will learn a lot in the process!